# How to inherit a class multiple times in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I need to inherit the purchase order class into two types. One is for purchase orders with products that can only be *sold*, and another one is for purchase orders with products that can only be *bought*.

I tried to inherit the core `purchase.order` object into two new custom objects. However it is not working.

My code is

```
from osv import fields, osv

class purchase_order_saleok(osv.osv):

  _inherit = 'purchase.order'
  _name = 'purchase.order.saleok'

  STATE_SELECTION = [
    ('draft', 'Draft PO'),
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('sent', 'RFQ Sent'),
    ('confirmed', 'Waiting Approval'),
    ('approved', 'Confirmed'),
    ('except_picking', 'Shipping Exception'),
    ('except_invoice', 'Invoice Exception'),
    ('done', 'Ordered'),
    ('cancel', 'Cancelled')]

  _columns =  {
    'state': fields.selection(
       STATE_SELECTION, 
       'Status', 
       readonly=True, 
       help="The status of the purchase order or the quotation request. A quotation is a purchase order in a 'Draft' status. Then the order has to be confirmed by the user, the status switch to 'Confirmed'. Then the supplier must confirm the order to change the status to 'Approved'. When the purchase order is paid and received, the status becomes 'Done'. If a cancel action occurs in the invoice or in the reception of goods, the status becomes in exception.",
       select=True
    )
  }

  purchase_order_saleok()

  class purchase_order_line_saleok(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
    _name = 'purchase.order.line.saleok'

  purchase_order_line_saleok()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? Does OpenERP create purchase_order_saleok table in database? Is it the same as purchase_order table?

Comment: It is not creating any table in database

Comment: On my server (6.1) it works ok. It created `purchase_order_saleok` table but the second one will be created when you add at least one column. Are you sure you added your file to `__init__.py`, restarted server and updated module?

Comment: When you inherit any model, it won't create new table it will use the existing table for that... I think possible solution for your problem could be just create multiple XML views with specifying filtering criteria instead of multiple objects..

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this, "I need to inherit the purchase order class into two types", that means you want two subclasses? Or you want to pass the instance into two other types?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add those tables to your database, you have to restart your server AND your module (as Lukasz Puchala said). Your code should create the new tables.

But i don't understand your first need, why don't you use **sale.order** for products than can be *sold*, and **purchase.order** for products that can be *bought* ?

Just for information :

You don't need to create a purchase.order.line.saleok (as it, it will never be used), because your purchase.order.saleok will keep its first **_fields** definition, and it will create standard **purchase.order.line** and not you're **purchase.order.line.saleok** (unless you override the field order_line, one2many, to be related on purchase.order.line.saleok).

Comment: Thanks Nonow Dev. Actually I need to separate the salable product and purchasable product. I will show in separate screens based on user. However I solved the problem. I created the inherited module and updated the purchase modules.